# javascript directions with google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how can i change the `start = $("#from").val();,`  value option, to users current position? It's more comfortable without typing the start adress.

Any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("pageinit", "#map_page", function() {
            initialize();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            calculateRoute();
        });

        var directionDisplay,
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            map;

        function initialize() 
        {   


            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507009, -0.170720);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom:16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: mapCenter
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));  
        }





        function calculateRoute() 
        {
            var selectedMode = $("#mode").val(),
                start = $("#from").val();,
                end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507009, -0.170720);
                //start = $("#from").val();

            if(start == '' || end == '')
            {
                // cannot calculate route
                $("#results").hide();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var request = {
                    origin:start, 
                    destination:end,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[selectedMode]
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                        $("#results").show();
                        /*
                            var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                            for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                            }
                        */
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#results").hide();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostition(successFunc)` or `navigator.geolocation.watchPostition(successFunc)`. `position`  with `.coords` with `.latitude` and `.longitude` properties are passed to `successFunc`. I recommend `.watchPosition` because the user's Browser will ask if it's okay to track location every time `.getCurrentPosition` is called. Note everything must be called inside `successFunc` that is dependent on `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude`, since those are Asynchronous methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

Comment: related question: [Uncaught exception when calling Google maps directionsService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476953/uncaught-exception-when-calling-google-maps-directionsservice)

Comment: related question: [Trying to display Google Maps Directions with Geolocation, and user input, using meteor. Everything but the actual directions work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544749/trying-to-display-google-maps-directions-with-geolocation-and-user-input-using)

Comment: related question: [Google directions don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752660/google-directions-dont-work)

Comment: Sorry guys, can't fix it by myself. After hours of trying: no result. Can someone help me with sample code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use https and not http for `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition()`